# Django rest framework social oauth2 и получения email залогиненого пользователя

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-api, django-rest-framework, oauth2

На своем бекенде настроил social authentication через facebook фронта пока нету. При тестировании ендпоинта http://localhost:8000/auth/convert-token/ создается юзер, но без email. Я проверил, действительно он не приходит. Хотя в настройках все есть

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = '<key>'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = '<secret>'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_API_VERSION = '3.2'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {'fields': 'id, name, email, picture'}
```

Вот [тут](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/) я нашел описание полей и там описано поле email - "The User's primary email address listed on their profile. This field will not be returned if no valid email address is available." Не ясно мне вообщем чего они хотят.
Подскажите кто-нибудь. Может что-то упустил. Email не может быть not available, на нем мой аккаунт facebook. Использую пакет django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 на бэке